# Django: how to get related foreign key set?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I'm working in Django 1.8. I have models like this:

```
class School(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'frontend'

class SchoolStatusOnDate(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    date = models.DateField()
    setting = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to retrieve all the statuses associated with a particular school, and I think I should be able to do it [using `_set` as described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), but it isn't working. This is my code:

```
s = School.objects.filter(code='A81018')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
SchoolStatusOnDate.objects.create(school=s, date=now, setting=4)
print s.schoolStatusOnDate_set.all()
```

But this gives me the following error on the final line:

```
AttributeError: 'School' object has no attribute 'schoolStatusOnDate_set'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`schoolStatusOnDate_set` should be lowercase.

From [Django documentation: Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

> If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a `Manager` that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this `Manager` is named `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name, **lowercased**.

*(emphasis mine)*